# QPython3 - Android One - How to open Browser URL and save page as HTML file?

Tags: android, pyautogui, qpython3

Simply put, how can I with QPython3 in my phone (Nokia w Android One), open a browser (any browser), go to a URL, and do a SAVE-AS on the page to store it in the /Downloads folder, as a single HTML file?

So far I have this code:

```
import pyautogui
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('google.com')
pyautogui.sleep(15)
pyautogui.hotkey('CTRL','s')
pyautogui.sleep(15)
pyautogui.hotkey('Alt','F4')
```

Those key presses are for Windows. I know! What's the equivalent inside an Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. I had to use [Tasker](https://www.androidauthority.com/automation-with-tasker-ifttt-qpython-762910/)